# Couldn't figure out this in an interview. Find the smallest cycle in this array?

Tags: algorithm

I need to find the length of the smallest cycle. For example, [1, 2, 1, 2] the length of the cycle is 2. Then [1, 2, 1, 2, 1] has a minimum length of 2. Then the length of 1, 2, 1, 2, 3 should be 5 because the entire list is not in repeat (I have no idea why this should be 5). The minimum length of 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2 is 5.

Here's what I tried to do: 
1.Use Dijkstra's algorithm and then go through the paths to find min length cyle
2.I tried to have a slow and fast pointer and then I found the cycle. I then walked through the cycle one more time to find the the total length of the cycle. I also have a set to not go through the same numbers again. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand the last example, why would 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2 give 2?

Comment: Another example I was given is  [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2] returns 5

Comment: I'm guessing it's 2 because of the 1-2 cycle

Comment: None of my guesses what could be meant with "a cycle in an array" is consistent with all the examples. A clear definition what a "cycle" is is needed.

Comment: Well if you start from the first point. Look at example [1,2,1,2]. 0->index 1-> index 2-> index1 that's a cycle. I don't get the 5 answer for [1,2,1,2,3[

Comment: If you apply the same pattern for the whole array, it would not match  [1,2,1,2,3] therefore the 5; but it also does not match [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2], so this should be 5 as well.

Comment: what pattern are you using? Maybe I got the example wrong for [1,2,1,2,1,1,2] and it is indeed 5

Comment: How would you do it in that case?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm

Comment: How would KMP even fit in this case? Never used KMP for something like this only for string matching

Comment: "I have no idea why this should be 5"... That makes the problem a bit harder to solve, doesn't it? did you ask the interviewer what smallest cycle precisely is?

Answer (score 2):

It *is* a little unclear what 'smallest cycle' means. Having said that, I think you may have overthought it a little. An easier way to think about it is to think about offsets. For example given an array `[1, 2, 1, 2, 1]` you can think about the ways this array matches when offset by a given amount. When the offset it two, it lines up perfectly:

```
offset = 2 cycle = [1, 2]
[1, 2, 1, 2, 1]
      [1, 2, 1, 2, 1]

offset = 5 cycle = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2]
               [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2]
```

With that in mind a brute force algorithm is pretty clear:

```js
function findCycle(arr) {
  let offset = 1;

  while (offset < arr.length) {
    let suffix = arr.slice(offset)
    // compare - does the array match everywhere with this offset
    let matches = suffix.every((n, i) => n === arr[i])
    // is so this is the smallest cycle
    if (matches) break
    offset++
  }
  console.log(offset)
}

findCycle([1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2])
findCycle([1, 2, 1, 2, 1])
// degenerate case:
findCycle([1])
findCycle([]) // 1 but maybe should be zero?
```